# How to improve an accumulator

Tags: function, python-3.x

In order to improve an accumulator I am writing a function to test if I am using an accumulator properly but I get stuck when I tried to write it even when I think the rest of my function is well code it.

Any information will be useful if you see something strange
Thanks in advance

```
def gather_every_nth(L, n):
    '''(list, int) -> list

    Return a new list containing every n'th element in L, starting at index 0.

    Precondition: n >= 1

    >>> gather_every_nth([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 3)

    [0, 3]
    >>> gather_every_nth(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i'], 2)
    ['a', 'c', 'e', 'g', 'i']
    '''

    result = []
    i = 0
    while i < len(L):
       result.append(L[i])
       i = result + result.append(L[i]) # I am not sure about this...

    return result
```

Comment: But here `n` is **not** an accumulator. An accumulator is a parameter passsed in recursion to store *state* of the recursion.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand why you think there is an *accumulator* here: the only thing that looks like an accumulator is `result`. But usually the term accumulator is used in the context of recursion.

This line:

```
i = result + result.append(L[i])
```

Is clearly problematic: `i` is supposed to be **an index** so an `int`. And here you add `None` (the result of any `.append` operation) to a list (?!) and what do you expect the outcome will be?

A way to fix this is simply:

```
i = i + n
```

or even shorter:

```
i += n
```

Nevertheless, you can reduce your entire code to a *one-liner* using *list comprehension*:

```
def gather_every_nth(L, n):
    return [L[i] for i in range(0,len(L),n)]
```

Comment: I tried by adding i = i + n but it seems that isnt work because return jyst the first element of L[]. I understand what I have to do but cant just write the code in this way. So frustrating. Sorry for my confused concepts of an accumulator. I will keep trying so any help will be useful. Thanks in advance

Comment: @user7491985: after rereading your question, I think the indentation after the `while` loop is also wrong.

Comment: You don't even need a list comprehension; this function is specified to only take lists, so you can just do `return L[::n]`.

Comment: after reading the instructions I must construct this function with a list comprehension. It seems by testing the function that only the i = .... section should be fixed somehow.

Comment: @user7491985: you *should* not construct the function by list comprehension, I'm only saying you *can* do that and that it is more elegant and efficient.

Comment: I see your point thank you so much for your help. I am just still stuck in that i = ... section after four hours ): Any hint will be welcome.

Comment: @user7491985: `i` is the **index** of the object you want to add to the list. In the `while` loop you first add it (the `append`, next you need to move the cursor (so the index), `n` places further. You do this by adding `n` to `i`. So you move the cursor `n` places to the right, check if it is still in the range of the list and if so add that element, and so on...

Comment: Ok I think I almost got it I am thinking how can check if it is still in the range of list. But at the moment I understand almost all. i = i + n and I need some other expression to indicate that add a element while Im in the range of the list. So must be something like this: i = i + n (while in range(len(L)) i guess

Comment: @user7491985: as long as `i < len(L)` - the condition you check in the `while` loop, it is fine. So that should work.